# Determine which Forms is on top

Tags: c#

I need a function that, given 2 form handle, can decide which one is on top of the other. Obviously we have two options:

1. The two forms don't intersect, and in this case the function should
   return 0
2. The two forms intersect, and the function should return -1
       or 1 depending which one is over the other

I've tried using GetForegroundWindow, and it works fine if those 2 are the only forms opened. What I need is a more general solution, that works everytime, even if none of the 2 forms has the focus. Any suggestion?

Comment: You'll need form Size, Position for the overlap test, then z-order.

Comment: You'll have to pinvoke GetWindow() with GW_HWNDNEXT to iterate the windows in Z-order.